# what is this in here (function literal)

Tags: javascript

I have the structure below that I dont understand the output very well.

```
var asker = {
    answer: "Its raining...",
    askQuestion: function(answered){
        console.log("Opps..." + this.answer);
        answered();
    }
}

//function literal
var debunker = function(){

    answer = "Its cloudy...";

    debunk = function(){
        console.log(this); 
        console.log("No way! The real answer is:" + this.answer);
    };

    return {
        debunk: debunk
    };

}();

asker.askQuestion(debunker.debunk);
```

It gives me these outputs

```
Opps...Its raining...
DOMWindow
No way! The real answer is:Its cloudy...
```

The `debunker.debunk` gets the answer that is `'Its cloudy'`. However `this` in the debunk function refers the `DOMWindow` so how `this.answer` can get the `Its cloudy` while it refers the `window` object ?

Comment: apart from your this problem, answer is no property of debunker.

Comment: Also your code calls a function called "answered" and you did not post any such function.

Comment: @Pointy: Check the args of the `asker.askQuestion` function ;)

Comment: ah ... not enough coffee this morning :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the introduction into the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You execute the function `answered()` in global context. As `answer` (in your debunker constructor) is not a private variable, it will be a property of the global `window` object.

Comment: Choose the best answer because you added extra reference link for details.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is because `answer` is *also* a property of the `window` object.  When defined without a `var` keyword, it becomes attached to the window.  With a `var` keyword, it is a private property of the function in which it is defined.

Answer (score 3):

`answer` is a global variable, because you do not declare it with `var`. That puts it in the scope of `DOMWindow`.

`this` is `DOMWindow`, so `this.answer` is "It's cloudy"